# How to dynamically insert a column name into the query! macro in Rust's sqlx

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I'm using the [sqlx crate](https://crates.io/crates/sqlx) to interact with a Postgres instance.

I have the following function:

```rust
pub async fn fetch_tweets_by_metric(
    pool: &PgPool,
    metric: &str,
) -> Result<Vec<Tweet>, sqlx::error::Error> {
    let tweets = sqlx::query_as!(
        Tweet,
        r#"
        SELECT * 
        FROM tweets
        ORDER BY $1 DESC
        "#,
        metric,
    )
    .fetch_all(pool)
    .await?;
    Ok(tweets)
}
```

I'd like to order the results by one of the columns in the table, passed in as `metric`. If I simply pass a string with column name it doesn't work (ie the code above is broken).

What's the right way to do it? I can't find anything in the docs / on google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macros are only usable with a constant SQL.

If your sql is dynamic, use the `query` function:

```
pub async fn fetch_tweets_by_metric(
    pool: &PgPool,
    metric: &str,
) -> Result<Vec<Tweet>, sqlx::error::Error> {
    let sql = format!(
        r#"
        SELECT * 
        FROM tweets
        ORDER BY {} DESC
        "#,
        metric,
    );
    let tweets = sqlx::query(sql)
        .fetch_all(pool)
        .await?;
    Ok(tweets)
}
```

Comment: Wow this worked, thanks! Question - how exactly does query(slqx) figure out to deserialize the results into Tweet struct, given we never explicitly pass it it? Does it somehow infer it from the return type of the function?

Comment: The job of inferring the right type in case of generics is done by the rust compiler. You need to specify it only when it can't be inferred.

Comment: Be very careful with this! This is strongly discouraged in the sqlx docs because if you have untrusted variables they can provoke sql injections.